# import named destinations in pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I m developing an application in which a word document is converted in pdf. My problem is too complicated please help me out.

My word doc has a toc, bookmarks, endnotes and hyperlinks. when I save this doc as pdf, only bookmarks are converted. After a long research I found that PDF documents does not support bookmark to bookmark hyperlinks, it needs either page number or named destinations.

So I choose named destinations for this purpose, but I am stuck again , because simple `"save as`" cannot generate named destinations in the pdf doc. So I print the word doc on adobe PDF printer and I got named destination as required, but again this document neither have bookmarks in it nor hyperlinks. so what I decided that I generate two pdf from a word, first by save as option and second one is by printing.

1. test.pdf (by save as) (contains bookmarks, hyperlinks)
2. test_p.pdf( by printing) (only contains named destination)

then I research ones again and found a way to extract all named destination from `test_p.pdf` into XML by a function of itextsharp.but unfortunately I dont get any way to import back this `xml` in `test.pdf`.. thats why I came here.

Guide me what to do next if this approach is ok. else suggest me any ohter approach to accomplish this mission.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a class to replace urls in my PDF files some times ago:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace ReplaceLinks
{
    public class ReplacePdfLinks
    {
        Dictionary<string, PdfObject> _namedDestinations;
        PdfReader _reader;

        public string InputPdf { set; get; }
        public string OutputPdf { set; get; }
        public Func<Uri, string> UriToNamedDestination { set; get; }

        public void Start()
        {
            updatePdfLinks();
            saveChanges();
        }

        private PdfArray getAnnotationsOfCurrentPage(int pageNumber)
        {
            var pageDictionary = _reader.GetPageN(pageNumber);
            var annotations = pageDictionary.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
            return annotations;
        }

        private static bool hasAction(PdfDictionary annotationDictionary)
        {
            return annotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE).Equals(PdfName.LINK);
        }

        private static bool isUriAction(PdfDictionary annotationAction)
        {
            return annotationAction.Get(PdfName.S).Equals(PdfName.URI);
        }

        private void replaceUriWithLocalDestination(PdfDictionary annotationAction)
        {
            var uri = annotationAction.Get(PdfName.URI) as PdfString;
            if (uri == null)
                return;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri.ToString()))
                return;

            var namedDestination = UriToNamedDestination(new Uri(uri.ToString()));
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(namedDestination))
                return;

            PdfObject entry;
            if (!_namedDestinations.TryGetValue(namedDestination, out entry))
                return;

            annotationAction.Remove(PdfName.S);
            annotationAction.Remove(PdfName.URI);

            var newLocalDestination = new PdfArray();
            annotationAction.Put(PdfName.S, PdfName.GOTO);
            var xRef = ((PdfArray)entry).First(x => x is PdfIndirectReference);
            newLocalDestination.Add(xRef);
            newLocalDestination.Add(PdfName.FITH);
            annotationAction.Put(PdfName.D, newLocalDestination);
        }

        private void saveChanges()
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(OutputPdf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(_reader, fileStream))
            {
                stamper.Close();
            }
        }

        private void updatePdfLinks()
        {
            _reader = new PdfReader(InputPdf);
            _namedDestinations = _reader.GetNamedDestinationFromStrings();

            var pageCount = _reader.NumberOfPages;
            for (var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
            {
                var annotations = getAnnotationsOfCurrentPage(i);
                if (annotations == null || !annotations.Any())
                    continue;

                foreach (var annotation in annotations.ArrayList)
                {
                    var annotationDictionary = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(annotation);

                    if (!hasAction(annotationDictionary))
                        continue;

                    var annotationAction = annotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.A) as PdfDictionary;
                    if (annotationAction == null)
                        continue;

                    if (!isUriAction(annotationAction))
                        continue;

                    replaceUriWithLocalDestination(annotationAction);
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

To use it:

```
    new ReplacePdfLinks
    {
        InputPdf = @"test.pdf",
        OutputPdf = "mod.pdf",
        UriToNamedDestination = uri =>
        {
            if (uri.Host.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("google.com"))
            {
                return "entry1";
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }.Start();
```

This sample will modify all of the urls containing google.com to point to a specific named destination "entry1".
And this is the sample file to test the above class:

```
void WriteFile()
{
    using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream("test.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
            {
                doc.Open();
                var blueFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLUE);
                doc.Add(new Chunk("Go to URL", blueFont).SetAction(new PdfAction("http://www.google.com/", false)));

                doc.NewPage();
                doc.Add(new Chunk("Go to Test", blueFont).SetLocalGoto("entry1"));

                doc.NewPage();
                doc.Add(new Chunk("Test").SetLocalDestination("entry1"));

                doc.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```